# Azure App Service - Copy folders between 2 App Services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have 2 App services. How to copy a folder (includes sub-folders) from one App Service to another internally? The two App Services are in PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

NO, there is no native way to do that. It's similar to how you copy files from one server to another. Because KUDU also does not support FTP.

You have todo download the files from one App and upload it to the 2nd one again. You can tools like WinSCP to do that. Also backup and restore is another option.

Comment: So is it possible to copy files between 2 deployment slots (if using deployment slots). WinSCP is not considered because the process must be performed in the backend with PHP.